# Combination of numbers

Tags: c#, angular, algorithm

I am working on online exam application,at the examine Login Question are displayed with `4` or `6` options. Let's take `4` options `a b c d`, if user select `a` then the value is `1` if `b` them value `2` if `c` then value `4` if `d` then value `8` if `e` value `16` if `f` then value `32`:

```
 a ->  1
 b ->  2
 c ->  4
 d ->  8
 e -> 16
 f -> 32
```

User may choose **multiple options**, let suppose user choose `a` and `b` then answer is `1 + 2 == 3` three is right answer or user choose `a d` then `1 + 8 == 9` is the correct answer.

what is the **logic** to break down `9` into `1, 8`  OR `11` into `1, 2, 8` or `35` into `1, 2, 32`?

Comment: Is this break down is static?

Comment: Binary numbers? `9 == 0b1001 == 0b1000 + 0b0001 == 8 + 1`

Comment: Static break down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bitwise operation seems like the way too go.
Since you tagged with Angular, I'll go with a Javascript solution :

```
function breakdown(input) {
    var values = [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32];
    var checked = [];
    for (v of values) {
        if (!!(input & v)) checked.push(v);
    }
    return checked;
}
```

Test cases:

```
breakdown(9)
> [1, 8]
breakdown(11)
> [1, 2, 8]
breakdown(35)
> [1, 2, 32]
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply convert your number e.g. 11 to binary. For 11 this gives you 1011. Now each figure of the binary number represents a selection option (but in reverse). Like in this case the person selected the first, the second and the last option.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.

```
        static void Main()
    {
        List<int> options = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 };
        List<int> selectedOptions = new List<int>();
        int aggrigatedAnswer = 22;
        BreakDown(aggrigatedAnswer, options, selectedOptions);

        Console.Write(string.Join(",", selectedOptions));
    }

    public static int BreakDown(int value, List<int> options, List<int> selectedOptions)
    {
        if (value <= 0)
            return 0;
        else
        {
            int option = options.Where(a => a <= value).Max();
            value -= option;

            selectedOptions.Add(option);
            BreakDown(value, options, selectedOptions);

            return value;
        }
    }
```

Output

```
16,4,2
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems the decomposition is based on *binary numbers*:

```
 9 => 0b1001 => 0b1000 + 0b0001 => 8 + 1 
11 => 0b1011 => 0b1000 + 0b0010 + 0b0001 => 8 + 2 + 1
```

**Code:**

```
private static IEnumerable<int> BreakDown(int value) {
  for (int power = 1; value > 0; value /= 2, power *= 2)
    if (value % 2 != 0)
      yield return power;
}

private static IEnumerable<char> BreakDownChars(int value) {
  for (int i = 0; value > 0; value /= 2, ++i)
    if (value % 2 != 0)
      yield return (char)('a' + i);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
int[] tests = new int[] {
   9,
  11,
  35,
};

string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,2} into {string.Join(", ", BreakDown(test))}"));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 9 into 1, 8
11 into 1, 2, 8
35 into 1, 2, 32
```

Or if you want *characters* (`a..f`)

```
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,2} into {string.Join(", ", BreakDownChars(test))}"));

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 9 into a, d
11 into a, b, d
35 into a, b, f
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

Code:

```
static readonly Dictionary<char,int> dict = new Dictionary<char,int>
{
    ['a'] = 1,
    ['b'] = 2,
    ['c'] = 4,
    ['d'] = 8,
    ['e'] = 16,
    ['f'] = 32
};

public static void Main()
{
    var i = 11;
    var answers = GetCombination(i);
    Console.WriteLine($"Letters: {string.Join(", ", answers.Keys)}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Numbers: {string.Join(", ", answers.Values)}");
}

static Dictionary<char,int> GetCombination(int i) =>
    dict.Where(p => (p.Value & i) == p.Value).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```

Output:

```
Letters: a, b, d
Numbers: 1, 2, 8
```

**Solution 2**

Code:

```
enum Dummy { }

static readonly Dummy[] dummies = new[] { 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 }.Select(d => (Dummy)d).ToArray();

public static void Main()
{
    var i = 11;
    var answers = GetCombination(i);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", answers));
}

static int[] GetCombination(int i)
{
    var dummy = (Dummy)i;
    return dummies.Where(d => dummy.HasFlag(d)).Cast<int>().ToArray();
}
```

Output

```
1, 2, 8
```